# nginx reverse proxy cache revalivation error

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We have a C/C++ app with an embedded http server. Our http server is very native, does not support ssl or keep-alive connection. It listen on port 5555 and servers static pages. Before serving the page, it gzip the response. It also supports cache validation with Etags. Depending on the `If-None-Match` value it sends `304 Not Modifed`. It work fine if we redirect our browser to `some-ip:5555`. Sample request and response header is as follows

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   max-age=3600, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding    gzip
Expires Wed, 15 May 2013 07:18:08 GMT

Request Headers
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Host    127.0.0.1:5555
If-Modified-Since   Tue, 08 May 2012 08:48:53 GMT
If-None-Match   "1336466933_85925"
Referer http://127.0.0.1:5555/mlogin.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.4) Gecko/20120425 Firefox/10.0.4

Response Headers From Cache
Cache-Control   max-age=3600, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  29832
Content-Type    application/x-javascript
Etag    "1336466933_85925"
Expires Wed, 15 May 2013 07:18:08 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 08 May 2012 08:48:53 GMT
```

Now when the same setup is tried with nginx reverse proxy, it gives `502 Bad Gateway` for all those page which tries to revalidate cache. It works fine for all page whose `Cache-Control   no-cache`. Our nginx configuration is as follows

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_requests 0;
    keepalive_timeout  0;

    server {
   server_name _;
   listen 80;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

   }
}
```

The response and request header then is

```
Response Headers
Connection  close
Content-Length  172
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 15 May 2012 08:46:31 GMT
Server  nginx/1.2.0

Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Host    127.0.0.1
If-Modified-Since   Tue, 08 May 2012 08:48:53 GMT
If-None-Match   "1336466933_85925"
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.4) Gecko/20120425 Firefox/10.0.4
```

In nginx error log we get this error

```
2012/05/15 14:16:31 [error] 18832#0: *177 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /lib/jquery-1.5.2.min.js?v=1330852144 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5555/lib/jquery-1.5.2.min.js?v=1330852144", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, your http-server breaks HTTP protocol somehow, e.g. doesn't send additional CRLF after last header.